# Should we validate path parameters in API?

Tags: go, validation, api-design

I have an API `/api/examples/:id` and `id` is stored in database as *Integer*. I also return 400 for validation error and 404 for resource not found.

Should I need to validate `id` data type in this API ? (Should I return 400 or 404 when  client pass `id` param as *String* like `/api/examples/abc` ?).

Comment: Do you NEED to validate ? No, you don't need to do it.

Is it better to do it thought ? Yes, a precise error handling is always better. Also, a wrong input of type/format should return a 400 bad request.

But ultimately, the most important is to keep the same behavior on all your endpoints.

Comment: @Magellan I understand, I will consider more. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you make a database query with it. So you should definetely check the input that no SQLInjection happens when forwarding the API parameter into your SQL-Statement.

You can do the check yourself by checking that id is an integer. Or you can use the mysql Driver capabilities to use parameters with `?` so it checks that the statement is valid and not breaking the query.

In fact you should do this anyhow.

If you just forward the id as a unsafe-string and do not use the correct sql capabilities but just append strings to a query and execute... you might be targetd by SQLInjection attacks. So yeah, either you should check the input or use the correct mysql driver functions to be safe here!